# Core of a set and its gauge

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A$ be a convex absorbing set in a linear space $X$ with gauge $p$. I want to show that

$\{x\in X: p(x)<1\}=$core of $A$.

We have $p(x)=\inf\{\lambda>0: x \in \lambda A\}$ and core of $A$ is the set of all $a$ in $A$ such that for all $x\in X\setminus \{a\}$ there exists  $0<r<1$ with the line segment
$[a, (1-r)a+rx)$ contained in $A$.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Your definition doesn't really match the normal definition of a core (compare with Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_interior ). The definition there asks for $[a,a+rx]$ to lie in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\in core(A)$ then $p(a)<1$.

Maybe part of the difficulty is that you are using an equivalent but more inconvenient definition of $core(A)$. Let me use the following definition: $a\in core(A)$ if and only if for all $d\in X$ there is $r>0$ such that $a+sd\in A$ for all $s\in [0,r]$.

Since $A$ is absorbing $0\in core(A)$.
Now let $p(a)<1$. Then $\frac1\lambda a \in A$ for some $\lambda\in (0,1)$. Hence we can write
$$
a = \lambda \cdot  \frac1\lambda a + (1-\lambda)0.
$$
That is, $a$ lies on the line between a point in $core(A)$ and a point in $A$. Then it follows easily that $a\in core(A)$: Let $d\in X$. Then there is $r>0$ such that $0+sd\in A$ for all $s\in [0,r]$. Taking the convex combination as above it follows that
$$
a+(1-\lambda)sd = \lambda \cdot  \frac1\lambda a + (1-\lambda)( 0+sd) \in A.
$$
Hence $a\in core(A)$.

The latter argumentation can be used to prove that the convex combination of a point in the closure of $A$ and a point in the algebraic (topological, relative) interior of $A$ is again such an interior point.

Comment: I think it should be  $s\in [0,r]$.